# How to compare strings in Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm stuck with this piece of code for a day now and can't get my head around as to why it doesn't work. Here's the code...

```
<div th:each="message : ${messages}">
    <p class="error" th:utext="${message.severity}"/>
    <p th:utext="${message.severity eq 'ERROR'}" />
    <p th:utext="${message.severity == 'ERROR'}" />     
</div>
```

The first tag outputs the value ERROR. However, the second and third tag evaluates to false. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. It turns out that the field I was comparing was an enum not a string. Sorry for my incompetence.

Answer (score 1):

For comparing `enums` you can do this

```
<div th:each="message : ${messages}">
    <p class="error" th:utext="${message.severity}"/>
    <p th:utext="${message.severity == T(YOUR_PACKAGE.YOUR_ENUM).SEVERITY}" />     
</div>
```